# How to call a method using ActionListener in GUI using Java2D

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, actionlistener

I am writing a graphical user interface program in Java that implements ActionListener. The program is a guitar chord visualizer using 2D graphics. I have a toolbar where the user selects what chord to be displayed. So in the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method, when the user selects a certain chord, that choice calls a method where the chord is displayed. However, when I test the program I get tons of errors. Here are the error messages

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fretboard.displayAMajor(fretboard.java:493)
    at fretboard.actionPerformed(fretboard.java:74)
    at java.awt.MenuItem.processActionEvent(MenuItem.java:650)
    at java.awt.MenuItem.processEvent(MenuItem.java:609)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:343)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:331)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Also, I am not using JPanel or JFrame. I am simply using Frame.
What is wrong with my program? Thanks!

Here is some of my code (The program is over 500 lines as of now).

```
public class fretboard extends Frame implements ActionListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new fretboard();
        frame.setSize(1280, 960);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * Create the menu bar and set title
     */

    public fretboard() {
        // Change the title of the window
        setTitle("Fretboard");
        // Create a menu bar where user will be given choice of chords
        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);
        Menu menu = new Menu("Chords");
        mb.add(menu);
     }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if("A Major".equals(command)) {
            displayAMajor();
        }
This method contains the bulk of my program. Here are just a few lines.

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Declare local variables
        int h = 40, w = 26, x = 695, y = 230;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 28);
        Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18);          
        // Declare the note variables
        // First string
        Ellipse2D E1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y-110, w, h);
        // Open the image
        File fretBoardFile = new File("/Users/macbook/desktop/Gibson_Fretboard.jpg");
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(fretBoardFile);
            g.drawImage(bi, 25, 25, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Draw notes
        // Draw the E note on the open 1st string
        // Change color to blue
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.draw(E1);
        g2.fill(E1);
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.drawString("E", x+5, y-80);
        // Change color back to blue
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);

public void displayAMajor() {
    // Declare local variables
    int h = 40, w = 26, x = 695, y = 230;
    Graphics g = null;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Graphics2D g2 = new Graphics();
    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 28);
    // Declare notes
    Ellipse2D E1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y-110, w, h);
    // Display notes for the A Major chord
    // Draw the E note on the open 1st string
    // Change color to red
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.draw(E1);
    g2.fill(E1);
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString("E", x+5, y-80);
    // Change color back to blue
    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: What variable is null at line 493 of the fretboard class?

Comment: So you expect us to debug your program without any code? That's like asking a mechanic to fix your car without bringing your car to his garage.

Comment: It is the Graphics2D variable that was created from a Graphics variable that I casted. I don't understand why I got this error message.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: but it makes this sound: "boom, chicka, boom, chicka, boom". Surely you must know what is wrong, right?

Comment: JT: as @MattiasBuelens states, you're asking us to be able read minds and see code that isn't shown. Please help provide more info so that this question is answerable.

Comment: My code is over 500 lines. Let me copy some of it down...

Comment: @JTWheeler It'd *really* help if you could post the code around that line, e.g. what variable you're casting and where you got it from.

Comment: See edit to answer. There shoudl be no surprise that you're getting a NPE since you're trying to use a null variable and trying to call methods on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, casting variables, null, graphics, I'm going to take a guess -- you're trying to save the Graphics object as a class field, you're casting it to Graphics2D, and it's null. If so, you'll want to read up on how to do drawing with Swing because that's not how it's done. You must use the Graphics object provided by the JVM and passed into a JComponent's (such as a JPanel's) `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. This is a decent link to start learning about [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) in Swing.

And again, you'll want to refactor your code because your class sounds *way* too big. Also you'll want to learn and use Java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case letters for instance.

Yikes, it's even worse:

```
Graphics g = null;  // *******  this is null!!!!
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;  // ***** it's *STILL* null!!
//Graphics2D g2 = new Graphics();
Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 28);
Ellipse2D E1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y-110, w, h);
g2.setColor(Color.red);   // ***** it's *STILL* null!!
g2.draw(E1);   // ***** it's *STILL* null!!
g2.fill(E1); // **** etc...
```

You're using a variable that is null, so it should be no surprise that it throws a NPE. Please read the tutorial that I've linked to.

You'll want to do your drawing either in the `paintComponent(...)` method override of a JPanel or other JComponent-derived class, either that or in a BufferedImage by extracting its Graphics object and drawing with that. If you're creating static images such as chord tabs, then BufferedImages will likely be the way to go, and then display them either in a ImageIcon held in a JLabel or in a paintComponent method.

Comment: The OP could also be trying to access the `getGraphics` method of a component that has not yet begin realized, but I think you assertion is more correct

Comment: Yep, that too. I'll probably end up deleting this SWAG soon.

Comment: I understand that now! However, I'm not sure how to correct this because I still need a Graphics2D variable in my dispalyAMajor() method. What do I need to initialize the variable to before using it? This stuff is pretty new and confusing to me still. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JTWheeler: see my edit to my answer. The key to this is not to guess at this stuff, because if you're like me, you'll guess wrong. You have to go through the tutorials to learn how it's done.

Comment: So the only way I can paint is with the paintComponenet(...) method? But I need to edit what I've painted when the user selects the chord.

Comment: @JTWheeler "I still need a Graphics2D variable in my dispalyAMajor() method"*, no, you don't.  You can only `paint` when the repaint manager tells you to.  In that case, you should prepare a proper state and request a repaint, when the repaint manager calls `paint` you update that state.  See the links from my answer

Comment: Thank you both for all your help! I will read through those tutorials and try to figure it out.

Comment: @JTWheeler: you can overlay images, you can draw on BufferedImages in the way you are describing, and then show the BufferedImage in a paintComponent method, there are a lot of tricks available.

Comment: I so far have drawn ellipses on the BufferedImage to represent the notes on the guitar in the paint() method. I just now need to edit some of those individual notes by changing the color to represent chords once the user makes the selection.

Comment: @JTWheeler: what you need to do is to break down your big GUI into little parts and start solving each little part in isolation, including the question above. Out of context, it can't be answered, but as part of a small program that you can post and we can modify, we can help in all sorts of ways.

Answer (score 2):

Just what did you expect from:

```
Graphics g = null;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

Also, your `paint` method breaks one of the most important rules of custom painting, it fails to call `super.paint` this is going to create more problems then it is worth listing.

The preferred method to override when performing custom painting is `paintComponent`, but, because you're overriding `Frame` (??) it doesn't have a `paintComponent` method.

Here's some ideas...

1. Use Swing components over AWT.  They're easier to use.
2. Extend from something like `JPanel` and perform your custom painting on it instead.  This provides you with more flexible design choices and cause less issues.
3. Always call `super.paintXxx`, if you don't, expect things to blow up in your face.
4. All painting MUST be done from the a `paint` method.  You do not control over the paint process, just accept it and move on.  You can encourage a repaint, but you must only paint from within the context of a `paint` method.
5. The `Graphics` context is controlled by the system.  If you want to paint on it, you must wait for one to become available, see previous point.  This context can change, so you should never maintain a reference to it.  The `Graphics` context is shared, failing to honor the paint chain will result in paint artifacts appearing

You might like to make the time to have a read through

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)